# Dividing by $\cos x \cdot \cos y$

Tags: trigonometry

When proving the addition formula for $\tan$:
$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}.$$

We start with (or at least everyone I've seen seems to do it this way):
$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\sin(x+y)}{\cos(x+y)}\cdot\frac{\cos x\cos y}{\cos x\cos y}$$

I'm confused now.. Is this an identity then?
$$\frac{\sin(x+y)}{\cos(x+y)}=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}.$$

When we divide by $\cos x\cos y$ we assume that $x$ and $y$ can't be equal to $\pi/2 + k\pi$ but in $\frac{\sin(x+y)}{\cos(x+y)}$ it can.

Isn't an identity an equality between the same function that is just differently defined (so the domain should be the same on both sides.)

I'm confused and I can't quite put a finger on what it is that confuses me.

EDIT:

Ok then, so the question boiled down to the definition of an identity:

Can two expressions be an identity if they have different domains?

The answers is yes apparently.

Comment: The identity makes no sense in case $x, y$ or $x+y$ are odd multiples of $\pi/2$.

Comment: Yeah, but can two expressions be an identity when they have a different domain?

Comment: Yep, they form an indentity in the intersection of the domains. Would be a pity to drop the whole identity for just a few isolated points.

Comment: Ohh. So two coinciding curves where one of them has holes in it?

Comment: I guess that answers the question then.

Comment: @amWhy: why not ?

Comment: @ Yves OOps, aye, *as she applies face to palm*

Answer (score 1):

By your argument , $x=x$ is not an identity as it  can be written as $$x=x\times {x^2\over x^2},$$ But The RHS is not defined for $x=0$ where as the LHS is.

So domains are not equal. !!

DO you see your fallcy?

Comment: Can't see it. ._." ... My thought was that $x=x\times {x^2\over x^2},$ is not an identity. I can't see how that means that $x=x$ is not an equality.

Comment: @arhean According to you , which one **identity** or **equality** requires an equality in domain?

Comment: Well, I thought that every identity has to have equality in domain. Apparently that's not the case.

Comment: An identity is an equality that holds true for all values of the variables. I assumed this means for all values of vars in the union of their domains; therefore, they would have to have the same domain to be an identity.

Comment: @arhean Now I changed my answer a bit. Have a look!

Comment: It is a matter of defining the domain on which both are defined. Just like $x= \dfrac{x^2}{x},$ $x$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R$; For $\dfrac{x^2}{x}$, it is defined on all reals, except $x=0$.  So the identity I write here is valid for all real x, except for $x=0$

Comment: Srry qwerty, I still don't get your point. My original "argument" was that $x=\frac{x^2}{x}$ is not an identity 'cause both sides don't have the same domain. How does that imply that $x=x$ is not an identity either?